# Merge tuples if their first element starts with specific string

Tags: python, nlp, tuples

I have a kinda tricky problem that I can't figure out how to resolve, so I'll try to explain it thoroughly. My dataframe has 5 columns, here's an example row:

```
 title                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             in_id    tar_id       in           tar  
[('<IN>This</IN>', 'DET', 'nsubj'), ('is', 'VERB', 'ROOT'), ('an', 'DET', 'det'), ('example', 'NOUN', 'compound'), ('text', 'NOUN', 'attr'), ('that', 'DET', 'dobj'), ('I', 'PRON', 'nsubj'), ('use', 'VERB', 'relcl'), ('in', 'ADP', 'prep'), ('order', 'NOUN', 'pobj'), ('to', 'PART', 'aux'), ('<TAR>get</TAR>', 'VERB', 'acl'), ('<TAR>an</TAR>', 'DET', 'det'), ('answer', 'NOUN', 'dobj')]    2137     2984      [1]       [12, 13]
```

So in the `title` we have a list of tuples, where the first tuple element is a word, the second is the part of speech tag, and the third is its dependency tree tag.

The `in` and `tar` columns are arrays that map to  the position of the words in the sentence that I want to mark either with 'word' or 'word' respectively.

The `in_id` and `tar_id` map to their ids.

What I want is this:

If in the `in` and/or `tar` there are more than one values (for example in the row I show `tar=[12, 13]`, I want the words at positions 12 and 13 to become one tuple instead of being two separate tuples.

So this `('<TAR>get</TAR>', 'VERB', 'acl'), ('<TAR>an</TAR>', 'DET', 'det')`

should become this:

`('<TAR>get an</TAR>', 'TAR', '')`

So the first elements of the 2 tuples merge, the second element gets renamed into the column name (either `IN` or `TAR` and the third element is empty.

```python
cols = list(df.columns)[4:]
for i in range(len(df))

parsed_sent = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    doc = nlp(row['title'])
    dep_sents = [(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_) for token in doc if not token.pos_ == "PUNCT"]
    for position, tuple_ in enumerate(dep_sents):
        word = tuple_[0]
        pos_tag = tuple_[1]
        dep = tuple_[2]
        for col in cols:
          if position in row[col]:
              word = f'<{col.upper()}>{word}</{col.upper()}>'
          else:
              word = word
    tuple_ = (word, pos_tag, dep)
    dep_sents[position] = tuple_
parsed_sent.append(dep_sents)
df['title'] = parsed_sent
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this should do. your indices start at one, it's weird and my code assumes they start at 0
the merging will happen on the first index

```
import re
def merge_tags(tag, indices, tuples):

    untar=re.compile(f'<{tag}>(.+)</{tag}>')

    tar_text=[]
    for i in indices:
        column,*_ = tuples[i]
        tar_text.append(re.match(untar, column).group(1))
    tar_text=' '.join(tar_text)

    for i in indices[1:]:
        del tuples[i]
        
    tuples[indices[0]]=(f'<{tag}>{tar_text}</{tag}>', f'{tag}', '')
    return tuples
    
tars=[11, 12] # in python indices start at 0
row=[('<IN>This</IN>', 'DET', 'nsubj'), ('is', 'VERB', 'ROOT'), ('an', 'DET', 'det'), ('example', 'NOUN', 'compound'), ('text', 'NOUN', 'attr'), ('that', 'DET', 'dobj'), ('I', 'PRON', 'nsubj'), ('use', 'VERB', 'relcl'), ('in', 'ADP', 'prep'), ('order', 'NOUN', 'pobj'), ('to', 'PART', 'aux'), ('<TAR>get</TAR>', 'VERB', 'acl'), ('<TAR>an</TAR>', 'DET', 'det'), ('answer', 'NOUN', 'dobj')]
print(merge_tags('TAR', tars, row))
>>> [('<IN>This</IN>', 'DET', 'nsubj'), ('is', 'VERB', 'ROOT'), ('an', 'DET', 'det'), ('example', 'NOUN', 'compound'), ('text', 'NOUN', 'attr'), ('that', 'DET', 'dobj'), ('I', 'PRON', 'nsubj'), ('use', 'VERB', 'relcl'), ('in', 'ADP', 'prep'), ('order', 'NOUN', 'pobj'), ('to', 'PART', 'aux'), ('<TAR>get an</TAR>', 'TAR', ''), ('answer', 'NOUN', 'dobj')]
```

you already know how to iterate over rows so i'll keep it to a minimum

```
row['title']=merge_tags('TAR', row['tar'], row['title'])
row['title']=merge_tags('IN', row['in'], row['title'])
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how to apply this to each row of dataframe and not only for 'TAR' but also for 'IN'